# Find$f(6)$ where $f(4)=\frac{f(8)}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$, $\int_4^8 \frac{[f'(x)]^2}{[f(x)]^4}dx=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)\neq 0$

We only know $f(4)=\frac{1}{4}, f(8)=\frac{1}{2}, \int_4^8 \frac{(f'(x))^2}{(f(x))^4}dx=1$ and find $f(6).$

How should I approach?

Substitution doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: verify that equality holds in C-S inequality $\int_4^{8} \frac {f'(x)} {f(x)^{2}}dx \leq \sqrt {\int_4^{8} \frac {f'(x)^{2}} {f(x)^{4}}dx} \sqrt {8-4}$. [The intergal on the left is $-\frac 1 {f(x)}|_4^{8}$ ]. This implies that ${f'(x)}/ {f(x)^{2}}$ is a constant $c$. Now solve this simple DE to find $f$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(x):=\dfrac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}$.

We are given
$$\int_4^8(g(x))^2dx=1\tag1$$
We can get
$$\int_4^8g(x)dx=\frac{-1}{f(x)}\bigg|_4^8=\frac{-1}{f(8)}+\frac{1}{f(4)}=2\tag2$$

Now, let us consider $\int_4^8(ag(x)+b)^2dx$ where $a,b$ are constants.

$$\int_4^8(ag(x)+b)^2dx=a^2\int_4^8(g(x))^2dx+2ab\int_4^8g(x)dx+b^2\int_4^8dx=a^2+4ab+4b^2=(a+2b)^2$$

So, taking $a=2$ and $b=-1$, we get
$$\int_4^8(2g(x)-1)^2dx=0$$
from which we have to have $2g(x)-1=0$, i.e. $(\frac{1}{f(x)})'=-\frac 12$ which implies $\frac{1}{f(x)}=-\frac x2+C$. So, $f(x)=\frac{-2}{x-2C}$. It follows from $f(4)=\frac 14$ that $C=6$.

Therefore, we finally get $\color{red}{f(6)=\frac 13}$.